# Print all stacktrace of all threads currently running in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to print all stacktraces of all threads currently running in Java process to stdout, to debug a deadlock of my server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, you can copy and paste the function body and use it without any import.

```
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Collection<java.lang.StackTraceElement[]> a1 = java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces().values();
    for (java.lang.StackTraceElement[] a2 : a1){
        System.out.println("==========");
        for (java.lang.StackTraceElement a3 : a2){
            System.out.println(a3.toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Above code has been tested on:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Why not just take a thread dump using `jstack` or `jcmd`? The JDK contains all utilities you need for something like this. No need to pollute your application code.

Comment: Thanks, looks like `jstack` is a better solution to my problem. I do not know why google do not tell me about it ...